# Using jQuery Sticky Navigation on Div After a Fixed Nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation, scroll

I am trying to implement the following jquery sticky_navigation code on a div that is below a fixed nav (total height being 120px). My problem is the script works by changing the div's position to fixed after scrolling past it (ie the top of the page). However by the time the user scrolls to the top of the page, the div is being hidden by top fixed navigation and causing a non smooth / jumping experience. I would like it to be trigger once the "Get Help Now" section reaches the bottom of the nav.

I would assume the fix would be something along the lines of changing the trigger point to be 120px below the scrollTop, but unfortunately i do not know how to code jquery and everything i have tried has failed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the jquery sticky_navigation code i am using and you can take a look at the staging site here, http://staging.alcoholrehab-florida.com/alcohol-rehab-programs.html

```
    <script>
    $(function() {

// grab the initial top offset of the navigation 
var sticky_navigation_offset_top = $('#sticky_navigation').offset().top;

// our function that decides weather the navigation bar should have "fixed" css position or not.
var sticky_navigation = function(){
    var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(); // our current vertical position from the top

    // if we've scrolled more than the navigation, change its position to fixed to stick to top, otherwise change it back to relative
    if (scroll_top > sticky_navigation_offset_top) { 
        $('#sticky_navigation').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':120, 'background':'#f0f0f0' }); });
    } else {
        $('#sticky_navigation').css({ 'position': 'relative', 'top':0, 'background':'#fff' }); 
    }   
};

// run our function on load
sticky_navigation();

// and run it again every time you scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
     sticky_navigation();
});

    });
    </script>
```

P.S. Please excuse any "protocol" errors, first time posting; long time reader.

Comment: What if you change it to 

( scroll_top > ( sticky_navigation_offset_top - 120 ) )

?

Comment: Perfect! That was exactly what i was trying to do. Just didn't know the proper way of coding it. Thanks.